# How to correct the Future Warning of loc?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I want to add an Nan row to my array, it runs well. But there is a FutureWarning: Slicing a positional slice with .loc is not supported, and will raise TypeError in a future version.  Use .loc with labels or .iloc with positions instead.
Nan1.loc[0, 0:4] = 'Nan'

How can I fix it?

```
import pandas as pd

data_down = [[1,34,5,2],
             [6,213,976,2]]
data_down = pd.DataFrame(data_down)
data_down.columns = ['Time', 'Current', 'Distance', 'Conductance']
print(data_down)
Nan1 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Time', 'Current', 'Distance', 'Conductance'])
Nan1.loc[0, 0:4] = 'Nan'

print(Nan1)

data_down = data_down.append(Nan1)
print(data_down)
```

Comment: just use `Nan1.loc[0] = 'Nan'` to add a full row of `'Nan'` strings.

Comment: just use Na1.loc[0, :] = 'Nan' in order to use all columns

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily by `append` in this way

```
data_down = data_down.append(pd.Series('NaN'), ignore_index = True)
```

Instead of this

```
data_down.columns = ['Time', 'Current', 'Distance', 'Conductance']
Nan1 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Time', 'Current', 'Distance', 'Conductance'])
Nan1.loc[0, 0:4] = 'Nan'

data_down = data_down.append(Nan1)
```